# Redux + react-router: Routing interception and redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am using Redux with react-router v3.

This is my routing setup:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={ hashHistory }>
    <Route path='/' component={ MainLayout }>
      <IndexRedirect to='accounts' />
      <Route path='*' component={ Accounts } />
      <Route path='accounts' component={ Accounts } />
      <Route component={ SubLayout }>
        <Route path='dashboard' component={ Dashboard }>
          <IndexRedirect to='overview' />
          <Route path='overview' component={ Overview } />
          <Route path='scan' component={ Scan } />
        </Route>
      </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

This is the logic I want to implement:(given user follows route '/')

1) MainLayout Component dispatches event to get profileData. If failed, redirect 
to another address

2) If successful, redirect to route 'accounts'

3) Accounts component makes a call to get account data.

The above works but there is a problem when the given route is '/accounts':
1) MainLayout does its thing and gets profile data then redirects to accounts which makes its call. BUT

2) the router navigates to accounts also making it to make another call.

Is there a better way of doing this? I basically want to redirect to the accounts page if no active account is set(in the store redux store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validate everything you need on your top-most responsible component (that is `MainLayout` in your case), making the appropriate changes to the redux store.

Either if it is successful or not, your child components should not do that validation again, unless it is strictly necessary (like a value that changes constantly). They should always check the store first because they are expecting their parent to have done it for them.

If you need to redirect because of the results of that validation, you can do  that on your children:

```
browserHistory.push('/some/path');
```

Redirecting will not re-render the parent, at least not as a general rule. React already knows that it will still have to rendered with the new route, hence it will not unmount it.

Comment: Im not sure that you understood what my problem is. Lets say I follow path '/ '  . My main component dispatches an action and can .push to accounts route. Accounts component does its thing. But a user can enter this route '/accounts'. Now same as above happens but react-router causes the accounts component to be constructed again

Comment: I think I understand what you mean but I am not sure that that is the problem. I think there is something wrong with the way I am using react-router. Currently, if I navigate to '/dashboard/overview' , I expect MainLayout to make a single call to fetch some data. It makes two. And the initiator of the second is listed as 'other'

Comment: @GilbertNwaiwu you can edit your question. Although I do not see how it makes two calls if you do **that call** in the parent. Note that **the parent** has to be the parent of both.

Comment: I think your approach of letting my MainComponent handle things is best. I swill have the issue of the component getting called twice though. What I want is prevent a route from being followed in the first place. How do i Do that?

Comment: @GilbertNwaiwu The route will be followed, that why you use react-router in the first page, which is not bad. See lifecycles, for a component which is called again, componentWillMount() will not be run for example, you can play with that. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle